# SQL Query to find closest match on products in the same box

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Recently, my company warehouse started receiving bundled products (we call them "kits") which have, in the same box, different products (mostly of the time, different in sizes).

We store them as we receive.

However, when we do not have a single item to ship (not inside a kit) we need to open the kit, and them split all the items into individual boxes.

I'm struggling to make a query which will return the oldest (OK, I can sort by `table_ID desc`) and the closest match.

My goal is, provided a list of items and quantities, always find the "best match" so in the end, I will have less work (and boxes) to split.

Consider a sample from my inventory (real table has a lot more data and columns like location, warehouse, price, etc, but they are not needed for the example):

In this example, If I'm asked to get 2 small blue shirts, the expected return should be kit number 5 and 6, because:

- kits number 5 and 6 is the "closest match" (would have been a "perfect match" IF I also asked for 2 medium blue) - the medium shirt is "collateral damage", and then I will unbox it anyway
- kits number 1 to 4 should be discarded, since they are the worst match (they have a LARGE inside)
- kit number 7 is also a candidate. However, since the inside shirt is another color, in a tie with the first rule, it should be less preferred

[image]

SQL Server is 2016 SP2 - Standard Edition

Comment: First you need to define the rules by which one match is better than the other.  That won't be sufficient to solve your problem, but it **is** a necessary early step.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think the following may work ? ( commented some parts to see the whole picture )

```
WITH Temp
AS (SELECT *,
           SUBSTRING(SKU, 1, CHARINDEX('_', SKU) - 1) AS Color,
           SUBSTRING(
                        SKU,
                        CHARINDEX('_', SKU) + 1,
                        CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING(SKU, CHARINDEX('_', SKU) + 1, CHARINDEX('-', SKU))) - 1
                    ) AS Product,
           REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SKU), 1, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(SKU)) - 1)) AS Size
    FROM dbo.Table_2),
     BestPick
AS (SELECT T.Kit_Number,
           T.QTY,
           T.Color,
           T.Product,
           T.Size,
           COUNT(T.QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY T.Kit_Number) AS Sum_KitCount
    FROM Temp AS T)
SELECT STRING_AGG(B.Kit_Number, ', ') AS BestPick,
       SUM(B.QTY) AS Total_IN_Kits,
       B.Color,
       B.Product,
       B.Size
FROM BestPick AS B
--WHERE B.Color = 'Blue'
--      AND B.Size = 'Small'
GROUP BY B.Color,
         B.Product,
         B.Size,
         B.Sum_KitCount
--HAVING SUM(B.QTY) >= 2
ORDER BY SUM(B.QTY);
```

Comment: Can you explain what does STRING_AGG() and CHARINDEX? Also, I should input all products (SKU) into the where clausule (size was just an example... in real world, sometimes the size is not "explicit" into the product code)

Comment: Oh, I am sorry , based on what you shared I created the query. STRING_AGG() is a SQL Built in function that concatenates the values of string expressions and places separator values between them. The separator is not added at the end of string and CHARINDEX() searches for one character expression inside a second character expression, returning the starting position of the first expression if found. hopefully I can help